# Obj-C Literals: Getting "Array subscript is not an integer" on an NSDictionary query

Tags: objective-c

Pretty simple:

[image]

Are you sure about that, Charles?

Clearly the "Array" is an NSDictionary and the "subscript" is a key.  This is the correct format for Obj-C literals.  This code worked in the test project I was building, but moving it over to my framework project, which pre-dates 10.8, it is broken, which makes me think this is something to do with project settings.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: You need to have the latest XCode (specifically LLVM 4.0) to compile this, and it also won't run pre-10.8.

Comment: Just use objectForKey, and save the fancy subscripting for the next release.

Comment: I'm on 10.8, and I'm running LLVM 4.0.  Thanks for the tips though, I think you're on the right track.  This works in one project but not in an older project on the same machine.  They both seem to me to be "up to speed" but clearly there is something that is preventing it from working the way it is supposed to.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your project:

```
@interface NSDictionary (subscripting)
- (id)objectForKeyedSubscript:(id)key;
@end
```

If you have trouble with other features check http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html and do the same with other subscripting equivalent methods. Subscripting probably works with the current beta out of the box.

Comment: Then you are not in ARC I guess. It should work in Xcode 4.4 if you tag the file with `-fobjc-arc` since subscripting is already in libarclite. In 4.4 without ARC you are out of luck I'm afraid.

Comment: I would say you are right, since the framework hasn't been brought over to ARC, but then again neither has the other project in which the code works.

Answer (score 0):

Change Architectures setting from 32-bit to 64-bit. It works for me with Xcode 5.1 in OS X 10.8.5.